# Can I use "zero out" to cancel?

Tags: phrasal-verbs

Can I say:

> We **zero out** the meeting because we knew it was going to be a failure.

Can I substitute "cancel" by "zero out?"

Answer (score 4):

I'm afraid you *cannot!*

Zero out has two meanings.

- [To eliminate](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/zero+out) (a budget or budget item) by cutting off funding - *the general meaning*.
- Zero out is a term used to describe taking a positive or negative value and making it null or zero - [*in the context of computers/programming*.](http://www.computerhope.com/jargon/z/zeroout.htm)

*zeroing out* the meeting sounds strange to me. I mean though *zero out* may mean 'cancel', it's not a synonym to be replaced.

---

As *zero out* may not work, you may need some other alternative.

I may say -

> We *called off* the meeting as we knew that it was not going to be *fruitful.*

Note: *failure* sounds *harsh* to me in such context.

Comment: Another suggestion to replace _failure_: _We called off the meeting because we knew it was going to be a **waste of time**._

Answer (score -2):

You can, but it would be:

> We cancelled the meeting because we knew it was going to be a failure.

*Cancelled* can (but does not directly) suggest a reschedule, as where to *zero out* something out tends to be a bit more final. But the two can be used quite interchangeably.

*Cancelled* is much more common.